# How does cargo decide whether to rebuild the deps or not?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I was thinking about skipping the dependencies building step in cargo. I have a simple project that uses 3 crates as dependencies mentioned in the `Cargo.toml`. I build the project once using `cargo build --release`. Now I had another project that used the same dependencies mentioned in its `Cargo.toml` file. I wanted to skip building deps for this project so I just copied the contents of my previous project's `target/release/` directory into the new project by creating a target directory in the root of the new project.

I ran `cargo build --release` for the new project but it built all the dependencies again. I thought that it would simply skip that step and just build my source code. Whereas if I build my old project again it doesn't take much time and doesn't rebuild the deps again since they are there in the target folder.

So I wanted to know what does cargo look for in the target directory to determine whether to rebuild the deps or not?

Comment: Could it be the `Cargo.lock` file?

Comment: I am not sure about it, lock file would only change if the Cargo.toml would change, if I build the project one and keep a copy of the build artifacts somewhere, and then do a cargo clean to delete all the artifacts and the copy the build artifacts back to the target directory and run a cargo build again then it builds all the dependencies again

Comment: I meant that maybe the missing lock file in the new project is the reason why cargo rebuilds the dependencies even though they are already in the `target` folder.