# How to cargo build only target but not dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I work on a Rust project that has a lot of packages as explicit or implicit dependencies (~420). When I want to rebuild the target after changing the `.env` file (that configures things like IP to download files from), I would like to rebuild only the packages that I authored, not all the dependencies.

How can I tell `cargo build` to use the previously compiled dependencies, but not use the previously compiled package that uses the `.env` file as input?

Ideally, `cargo build` would realize that the `.env` file has changed and automatically decide to rebuild only the parts that use the `.env` file, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case.

So the second best solution is to manually tell `cargo build` at which point in the build graph to start off again.

We're using the dotenv crate https://crates.io/crates/dotenv crate to read the `.env` file.

I tried `cargo clean -p nextclade` to tell it to clean only the package in question that I'm working on - but that still cleans up all the dependencies which cause my build to take 5 minutes rather than 2 minutes (if using compiled dependencies).

There's a question that seems to ask a similar question, but that question is actually a different use case/set up, so it's not a duplicate: [How does cargo decide whether to rebuild the deps or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61095844/7483211)

Comment: I know that you can specify non-rust dependencies [using build.rs scripts](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#change-detection) ([more](https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/aig2iv/cargo_reliable_code_generation_declaring/)), I'm not sure that's supported declaratively, [The manifest format](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html) has nothing.

Comment: That sounds smart @Masklinn. The root problem may be a bug in `dotenv` on macOS - because for my colleague on linux the `.env` file seems to be watched correctly and used after changes.